# How to add attributes to entity framework model class without losing them after update database

Tags: c#, .net, model, frameworks, entity

I want to add attributes on properties inside my model class. But I know if I create new changes in database and update my model the attributes added will be removed. So my question is can I manipulate the model class into a POCO and reference the POCO instead of using EF model class when I do IQueryables.

```
public IQueryable<UserAccount> GetUserAccounts()
{
    return Entity.UserAccounts;
}
```

`UserAccount` is an auto generated template model class which was created by EF. Can I have my own model to have data annotations ?

Comment: After changing the model class you can add the migration and run update database command

Comment: sorry I forgot to mention but I am using database first approach. I dont know if this is relevant.

Comment: Look at what a "migration" is

Comment: Yes I know. But is it the best approach to change the model class EF created since it has been auto generated ?

Comment: Generated classes are typically `partial` so you can add to them in a separate file. For things like attributes for existing properties, look up `MetadataType` or similar constructs that allow you to place the attributes on a structurally equivalent but separate class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hy,
The best approach is that you keep the autogenerated class as it is, which makes it more clean and extend class with a partial class  containing the extra properties you want.